# How to find duplicates in a list of tuples?

Tags: haskell, tuples

What would be the best way to filter through a list of tuples and return only the ones where the `fst` and `snd` value are the same ?

```
[(2,1),(2,2),(3,1),(10,9),(10,10)]
```

would return `(2,2)` and `(10,10)`.

Comment: I like the question, because it rhymes.

Comment: @ziggystar: In some accents, maybe…

Answer (score 13):

The easiest way is to just use `filter` with a lambda: `filter (\ (a, b) -> a == b) ls`.

You could also be cute and use `uncurry`, which changes a normal function of two arguments into one that takes a tuple, giving you `filter (uncurry (==))`. Remember that `(==)` is just a function of type `Eq a => a -> a -> Bool`, so `uncurry (==)` is a function of type `Eq a => (a, a) -> Bool`, which is exactly what you're looking for.

Comment: @cockmagic: If this answer solved your problem, you can accept it with the checkmark under the vote arrows, which will mark this question as solved.

Comment: a word of warning, `let filterEquals = filter (uncurry (==))` defaults to the type `[((),())] -> [((),())]` which is incompatible with the list, so a type signature must be provided if one wasn't already.

Comment: @ElectricCoffee: That's a good point. The dreaded monomorphism restriction strikes again! What's worse is that the type error message I get if I try it (as a toplevel definition in a file) is completely unintelligible.

Comment: @ElectricCoffee: Happily, if you're using a new version of GHC, the monomorphism restriction is turned off by default in `ghci`, so `let filterEquals = filter (uncurry (==))` types correctly at the repl.

Comment: which version you referring to? I'm running 7.6.3

Comment: @ElectricCoffee: It's been turned off by default in `ghci` since 7.8.1, I believe.

Answer (score 5):

You can do it using list comprehensions:

```
doubles ls = [(x,y) | (x,y) <- ls, x==y]
```